# Contact Form 7 custom placeholder text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a contact form on every post. I am trying to display a different placeholder text on subject field on every post, where subject field placeholder text should be equal to the post title.

So this is current contact form tag:

```
[text text-900 placeholder "Subject"]
```

I tried replacing *Subject* with

```
<script>
 $("input").val("<?php echo $post; ?>");
</script>
```

but it hasn't worked.

Please help me solve this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery('.wpcf7-form input[type=text]').attr("placeholder", "Your Post Title")
```

Complete PHP Code is below. Tested.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.wpcf7-form input[type=text]').attr("placeholder", "<?php the_title(); ?>");
</script>
```

Comment: I wasn't specific enough, my apologies. Contact form has multiple text input fields, I would just like to replace one of them with a specific title. So I would first need to add some sort of ID to the field I'm trying to influence. Second thing is, the code literally puts <?php the_title(); ?> as a replacement, so it doesn't seem to do anything with the php code.

Comment: Yes you can use `Subject` field `ID` instead of `input[type=text]`.

Answer (score 0):

First add the class like this as per the docs of contact-form 7

```
 [text class:subject_form text-900 placeholder "Subject"]
```

then on somewhere at top of your .php file initilalize the global variable of title

```
<script>
   page_title = "<?php echo the_title()?>";
</script>
```

then

in jQuery

```
<script>
   jQuery('.wpcf7-form input.subject_form').attr("placeholder", page_title);
</script>
```

Comment: This is how I used the code (I removed other input fields for easier understanding):       <script>
   page_title = "<?php echo the_title()?>";
</script>
<div class="fusion-one-half fusion-layout-column fusion-column-last fusion-spacing-yes">[text* text-900 class:subject_form placeholder "Subject"]</div>

<script>
   jQuery('.wpcf7-form input.subject_form').attr("placeholder", page_title);
</script> and this is what it does: http://prntscr.com/laawlg

Comment: [text* text-900 class:subject_form placeholder "Subject"] has to be used inside the contact form editor in wp-admin, not directly inside page builder.

Comment: Yes, I copied the code from the contact form editor :)

Comment: Yes, I copied the code from the contact form editor :)